# how to write the log file into database table?

Tags: magento2, payment, payment-gateway, log

I have a log file (payment.log) want to write into database table, is there any reference I can follow?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not write file -> database for security reasons. Why don't you find the point where the log is written and connect a plugin that writes to a custom table?
Check if the class is a public function, at which point you can safely generate an afterExecute by following the magento 2 guide lines: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

For create a new custom table:

- if magento >2.3 version -> db_schema.xml https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html
- if magento <2.3 version -> installSchema.php -> https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-new-table-to-database/

Cheers